# How to hide external API token at .Net ( SOLVED)

Tags: javascript, .net, api, environment-variables, token

I am working on an .net 5 web api projectt. I needed to  use an external api (rapidapi.com etc.) . These websites gave me a apitoken.
I know i should hide it , so no one at github would see it.

But also i should sent my apikey to my teacher so he could acces to, or hecan acces with his own apikey.

1.where sholud i store it?
2.How Should i store it?
3.How can i call it?

I know how to do it  at JS, (its so easy, create .env file, and call it einvironmet.apikey ) ,  but don't know  at .net.
I need a simple solution like js

EDİT: I found a solution.
you can add a section at appsettings.json
like this

```
"API_KEY": "blablabla"
```

then use this in your controller
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

create ctor for this

```
public CurrencyCalculatorAPI(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
```

then use your apikey like this

var apiKey = _configuration.GetValue("API_KEY");

you can use it wherever you want

Answer (score 1):

You should use "User secrets", as [described by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows).

It's very easy in Visual Studio where you just right click your project and choose "Manage User Secrets". This will create a file in this location: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user_secrets_id>\secrets.json`

This file is outside your project so it will never be a part of what you have in Github.